# Receiving notifications in Stack Overflow chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

Many of us will at least occasionally visit the [Stack Overflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) (including myself) and sometimes may not always monitor other Stack Overflow pages.

Often I will receive messages, important messages such as suggestions/important information/answers (and just as often thank you messages) (on Stack Overflow main site) while in these chat rooms and I do not want to miss any of them.

To a certain extent this is annoying because it is not possible to see any messages while in a chat room.

It seems odd that it has not been included here especially since the inbox and user-profile is available everywhere else.

Could we please have  this feature added to the Stack Overflow chat and if not why has this not been done?

Comment: On my system, Chrome 64, when I receive a reply to a chat message, a beep sounds, and the tab flashes... is that not what you hear/see? I also don't understand the statement "it is not possible to see any messages while in a chat room", because, that is, after all, what a chat room is...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No I mean messages from SO main-site while in the chat rooms.'

Comment: There is [Top Bar for Chat Rooms](https://stackapps.com/questions/7404/top-bar-for-chat-rooms) but I haven't seen JasonC around lately so I'm not sure if it still works after the new topbar went live. I assume he doesn't mind if you submit PR's to get it up to date with the current topbar.

Comment: @rene  That's exactly what I'm after

Comment: @rene - it's still working, can confirm; it seems to pull the top bar directly from chat.<domain>, and chat hasn't received an updated topbar yet.

Comment: Super. I'll use that then :-)